Constrained optimization over a set of functions
How to approach the following optimization problem:
$$\text{minimize }\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$$
over all (integrable) real-valued functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ satisfying
$$1-x_1 x_2 \leq f(x_1)f(x_2)\text{ for all }x_1,x_2 \in [0,1]?$$

Note that the constant function $f=c$ satisfies your conditions for any real $c\le-1$. So,
$$\inf\int_0^1 f=-\infty.$$


Consider now the same problem but with the additional condition $f\ge0$.
Then, for all $x\in[0,1]$ (using your condition on $f$ with $x_1=x=x_2$), we have
$$f(x)\ge\sqrt{1-x^2},$$
whence
$$\int_0^1 f\ge\int_0^1 dx\,\sqrt{1-x^2}=\frac\pi4=0.78539\ldots.$$

With a bit more effort, we can do better than that: for all $x\in[0,1]$ (using your condition on $f$ with $x_1=x$ and $x_2=1-x$), we have
$$\sqrt{1-x(1-x)}\le\sqrt{f(x)f(1-x)}\le\frac{f(x)+f(1-x)}2,$$
whence
$$\int_0^1 f\ge\int_0^1 dx\,\sqrt{1-x(1-x)} 
=c:=\frac{1}{8} (4+\ln27)=0.9119\ldots.$$
On the other hand, if $f(x)=c_1\sqrt{1-x(1-x)}$ for
$c_1:=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}}$ and all $x\in[0,1]$, then your conditions of $f$ will hold. So, the lower bound $c$ on $\int_0^1 f$ is optimal up to the factor $c_1=1.0745\ldots.$

The upper bound $c_1c=0.97998\ldots$ on $\inf\int_0^1$ can be further improved a bit, by letting
$$ f(x)=f_a(x):=c_1(a)\sqrt{1-ax(1-x)}$$
for $a\in(0,4)$, $c_1(a):=\sqrt{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{4-a}}}$, and all $x\in[0,1]$. Then your condition on $f$ holds, and the minimum of
$\int_0^1 f_a$ over $a\in(0,4)$ is $c_*=0.96360\ldots$ (attained at $a=2.3331\ldots$). So, the lower bound $c$ on $\int_0^1 f$ is optimal up to the factor $c_*/c=1.0566\ldots<c_1=1.0745\ldots.$


I would be much (and pleasantly) surprised if $\inf \int_0^1 f$ is explicitly determined (assuming additionally that $f\ge0$).

While this answer is technically correct, I am willing to bet that Arkadi had in mind that $f$ must be non-negative...

@AlekseiKulikov : This is what I suspected. On the other hand, I see "real-valued".

@AlekseiKulikov : The case $f\ge0$, too, has now been (partially) considered.

You are right: I meant f real-valued non-negative. The upper bound on the integral is particularly helpful.
